# Form if succes function and replace image back

Tags: jquery, forms

I have multiple forms in a modal window. When somebody hits the submit button the data is send to the server correctly. To make things clear for people I want to change the submit button to a loading image when clicked and when the data is submitted I want it to change back to text like "send" or "succes!" or whatever. Problem is that my forms are generated dynamically and submitted in the old fashion way.

So in short:
How do I make a success function so when data is submitted the loading image can be changed back to some succes text.

My script:

```
          $.each(data.product.variants, function(index, variant){     

        contentHtml = contentHtml +
          '<div id="form">' +
          '<form class="formProduct" id="formProduct'+variant.id+'" action="{{ 'cart/add/' }}'+variant.id+'" >' + //method="post" delete this cause it needs to be GET
          '<div class="variants">' +
          '<div class="pop_variantTitle"><label><input type="hidden" id="variantId" value="' + variant.id + '" />' + variant.title + '</label></div>' +
          '<div class="pop_variantQuantity"><label">{{ 'Quantity' | t }}: <input type="text" name="quantity" id="formProductQuantity" value="1" /></label></div>' +
          '<div class="pop_variantAdd"><input type="submit" class="submit button green" id="submitter" value="In winkelwagen"/></div>' +
          '<div id="divMsg" style="display:none;"><img src="https://webshop.com/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Even geduld..." /></div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</form>' +
          '</div>';
      });     
      $('.formProductContent').html(contentHtml);
    });     
    $().ready(function(){

      var form = $('form').attr('id');

      $(form).submit(function() {
        return false;
      });

       $('form').live('submit', function(){      

        $(this).replaceWith("<img src='https://webshop.com/ajax-loader.gif'>");
        $.get($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){

          // if succes

        },'json');
        return false;
      });
    });
   }
 });
return false;
 })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an ID or class?

try this:

```
$('form').live('submit', function(){      

        $(this).replaceWith("<img id=loading src='https://webshop.com/ajax-loader.gif'>");
        $.get($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){

          // if succes
         $('#loading').replaceWith("<img  src='https://webshop.com/success.jpg'>");  
        },'json');
        return false;
```

Comment: `live` is not longer used in the never versions of jQuery. You should use `.on` instead: `$('#formID').on('submit',function () [...]`

Comment: @Martin Borthiry: I thought about this the same, but I actually don't really know what to do when I post a form like described in my post above and then what to do in the success function. So I've made it so that when I hit the submit button the modal stays open but somehow an user needs to know that there is something "working". Do you know what I can do in the success function?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommed you *not* using standard jquery-ui widgets for these "non-standard" cases, or you'll end up soon with lots of hackish code, that does its job in a way-too-complex way.

Instead, I'd recommend you to write your own form-submitting dialog widget, whose "Save" button is actually the form "submit" button, etc.

You can create a dialog easily by using some jquery.ui facilities, such as `.draggable()`, `.resizable()` and `.position()`.

**Handling the dialog form submit**

In short, once you created your dialog, you can do something like this:

```
// $your_dialog is the main container for the whole dialog thing..
$('form', $your_dialog).submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var dialog = this;

    // load data from the form to "data"

    $("button[type=submit]", this).html("Submitting...");

    $.ajax('/submission/url', {
        type:"POST",
        data:data,
    })
    .success(function(data){
        $("button[type=submit]", dialog).html("Success");
    })
    .error(function(data){
        $("button[type=submit]", dialog).html("Failure");
    });
});
```

**Some other notes about your code**

```
  var form = $('form').attr('id');
  $(form).submit(function() {
    return false;
  });
```

what this piece of code does is.. retrieve the id of the (first) `<form>` on the page. Luckily, it's actually `form`, and as such the second jQuery call will be.. `$('form')`

Why don't you use this instead?

```
  $('form').submit(function() {
    return false;
  });
```

Also, it is recommended for many reasons to use `.preventDefault()` in order to prevent default event handling, instead of making the handler return false. So:

```
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    event..preventDefault();
    // .. rest of your code ..
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I can do something with that. You mention that I can use code for jquery ui dialog. Problem is that I'm using eric martins simplemodal. Can I use this code for that as well?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I can do something with that. You mention that I can use code for jquery ui dialog. Problem is that I'm using eric martins simplemodal. Can I use this code for that as well?

Comment: I had a quick look at the simplemodal demo, and it looks like you aren't forced to use generated limited-functionality buttons like in jquery.ui. So, yeah, you should be able to just create a dialog containing your form with submit handler attached, without even having to use any jquery.ui function (just plain jquery).
Just remember to add the ``simplemodal-close`` class to your buttons (or to call ``$.modal.close();`` in you handler, which is probably better).

Answer (score 0):

Submitting the form will cause a postback so you would either have to add something in the .ready() event, or maybe use ajax and provide a success callback